# Angular $http post not working with asp.net mvc sending null data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-services, http-post

I'm Stuck with calling C# web API from angular $http post method as below.

My JSON Object is as below

```
var requestParams = {
    "CostObjects": $scope.costObjForSaveArray,
    "CostObjectHierarchies": $scope.costObjHierarchyForSaveArray,
};
```

API Call with Angular is as below

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: API_ROOT + "BusinessDimension/UpdateCostObjects",
    data: requestParams,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

Now the API written in .NET is as below.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("UpdateCostObjects")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCostObjects([FromBody] JsonData data)
{
    var costObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CostObjectM>>(data.Data);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var updatedCostObjects = Acornpadomainservice.UpdateCostObjects(costObjects).ToList();
        return Request.CreateResponse(updatedCostObjects);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

JSON class is as below

```
public class JsonData
{
   public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Could anyone correct me what's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your function gets called , but the data is null?

Comment: Yes @gaurav5430: But the data is show in Request Payload in chrome xhr network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the following code

```js
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: API_ROOT + "BusinessDimension/UpdateCostObjects",
    data: {Data :angular.toJson(requestParams)},
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

The angular.toJson(data) will stringfy you object because the Json object is expecting a string type on a Data field to be sent to it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your post method parameter type to **object** or **string** in replace of **JsonData**  and check if it's working or not..

Eg.

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("UpdateCostObjects")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCostObjects([FromBody] object data)
    {
        var costObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CostObjectM>>(data.Data);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var updatedCostObjects = Acornpadomainservice.UpdateCostObjects(costObjects).ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(updatedCostObjects);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: API_ROOT + "BusinessDimension/UpdateCostObjects",
  data:  JSON.stringify(requestParams),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

Comment: I request you to please add some context/commentary around the code you have shared. It will help the asker and other readers to understand your post better.

Comment: @RBT who asked the question didn't verify any answer or reply to anyone of us .. !!!!